# Not able to put text in box using HTML 5 canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am getting problem to add **text** inside this box. I am using "HTML 5" canvas animation to slide box from left to right but i am trying to put some text inside it. I tried to put
many syntax for that but not able to do it. What to do?

Code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
   <head>
     <style>
   body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  <script>
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
     window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    })();

    function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
    context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
    }
    function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
     // update
    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

    var linearSpeed = 50;
    // pixels / second
    var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

    if(newX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
      myRectangle.x = newX;
    }

    // clear
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function() {
      animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
    });
   }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var myRectangle = {
    x: 0,
    y: 75,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 5
  };

  drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

  // wait one second before starting animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
    }, 1000);
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just added this statements in your **drawRectangle** function:

```
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
context.fillText("Zibri", myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y + 30);
```

There is not the optimus :) but now you can start to refactor :)
For your reference

> fillText()
>
> Draws the specified text using the text style specified by the font
>   attribute, the alignment specified by the textAlign attribute, and the
>   baseline specified by textBaseline.  The text is filled using the
>   current fillStyle, and the strokeStyle is ignored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
             window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function (callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
        })();

        function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
            context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.stroke();
            context.font = "bold 16px Arial";
            var myText = "Zibri";
            var centerX = myRectangle.width / 2 - (context.measureText(myText).width / 2);
            var centerY = myRectangle.height / 2;

            context.fillText(myText, myRectangle.x + (centerX), myRectangle.y + centerY);
        }
        function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
            // update
            var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

            var linearSpeed = 50;
            // pixels / second
            var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

            if (newX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
                myRectangle.x = newX;
            }

            // clear
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

            // request new frame
            requestAnimFrame(function () {
                animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
            });
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var myRectangle = {
            x: 0,
            y: 75,
            width: 100,
            height: 50,
            borderWidth: 5
        };

        drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

        // wait one second before starting animation
        setTimeout(function () {
            var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One more thing if i wanted this text to be in center then is there any other syntax needed...?

Comment: you can use _ctx.measureText(text).width_ to get the width of your text, so you can easily calculate the exact position of your text